# How to prevent from link to a special website inside a flash file using PHP command

Tags: php, flash

There is a webpage based on PHP which use a swf flash file.

inside .swf flash file there is a link connection to a website like

`something.com`

How can i write a code for preventing it to connect to `something.com` from inside PHP file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You are going to have to change the fla file and compile it and then use the new swf. Why? Because the swf runs on the client side. So, when the swf tries to open a page, the client will decide whether to allow or deny it, and in most cases, clients allow.

Remember, the swf will not poll your php asking if it has permission (unless it is so designed) so you don't have much of a choice, really.